# How to use query to filter data based on certain conditions in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, conditional-statements

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have 3 conditions from column B to column D. `T`= to the condition fulfilled in that particular date and `F` otherwise. All the 3 conditions have their own `T` and `F` in each date.

**What I want to achieve is:**

When I select `On` for condition 1, `Off` for condition 2 and `On` for condition 3, the `QUERY` function able to ignore the Condition 2 and give me the rows of the date where Condition 1 = `T` and Condition 3 = `T`. So basically if the Condition 2 is `Off`, then the query function will just looking at Condition 1 and 3 and extract the date where `Condition 1` and `Condition 3` is equal to `T`.

The data in column F is the expected output based on the `On Off` condition in `B2:B4`. May I know is there any way that I can achieve this automation? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zOB2rrysOQ7V6_Pa-caQN94Y-gFI_JT2gJ9Hf6tZQi8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, in C2 `=if(B2="On","B='T'",)` then C3 `=if(B3="On","C='T'",)` then C4 `=if(B4="On","D='T'",) then in` C5

```
=textjoin(" and ",true,C2:C4)
```

then

```
=QUERY(A8:D16,"Select A " & if(C5="",,"where "&C5&" "),1)
```